# how to create a url pattern on path(django 2.0) for a *item*_id in django

Tags: python, django

Here's my code

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
# /audios/
path('', views.audio ),

# /audios/4344/
path('(<record_id>[0-9]+)/', views.record_detail),
]
```

Please can someone help out

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
path(r'^record/(?P<record_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.record_detail)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 2.0 has came with new update of defining a new way for url patterns by **path**. In new url patterns you don't need to define urls in regex(see 3rd url pattern). [Refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path)

But you can also write url patterns like we define in django < 2. 0 by **re_path** which is available in **django.urls** [refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path)

Or you can use old django style of defining url patterns which is defined in **django.conf.urls** which helps you to define re pattern for urls.

```
from django.urls import re_path, path
from djnago.conf.urls import url,include 

urlpatterns += [
       url('(<record_id>[0-9]+)/',views.record_detail),
       #or 
       re_path('(<record_id>[0-9]+)/', views.record_detail),
       #or
       path('<int:record_id>/', views.record_detail) 

    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Exprator wrote, the path should be:

```
path('<int:record_id>/', views.record_detail, name='record_detail'),
```

However, I think maybe there is a problem in view "record_detail", the view should declare like this:

```
def record_detail(request, record_id):
```

then, you can refer your record_id in your view body. 
Here is my code:

`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:record_id>/', views.record_detail, name='record_detail'),
]`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")

def record_detail(request, record_id):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're record is: "+str(record_id))
```

Here is result:
[image]

Comment: thanks alot ... i switched back to using `url` not `path`